# Dojo js Select and onchange function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, dojo

I am using dojo.js to make dropdown box with scroll functionality, something not native to standard select statement.

I have managed to create the dropdown menu but I am having difficulty getting it to execute a function using the standard onchange attribute of the select statement. onchange = "updateData()" in this case.

Grateful for any help.

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>drop down</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="d3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
    <script>dojoConfig = {async: true}; </script>
<script src='d3/dojo/dojo.js'></script>  
<script src='d3/dijit/dijit.js' ></script> 


    <script> 

var djConfig = {
    isDebug: true}; </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
require(["dojo/widget/Select"]);</script> 

    <script> 

require(["dojo/parser"], function(parser) {
parser.parse();});
    </script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <style>                                        
        #dropdown{

            font-size: 22px;
            font-family:  serif;
            color: grey;}
                   </style>




</head>
<body>

<div class="claro">
        <select 
 id="dropdown" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select" data-dojo-props="maxHeight:50" 
 style="width: 100px" onchange= "updateData()" >

            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
        </select>
    </div>         


 <script type="text/javascript">


 //The following is used to reset the dropdown box to original value on pg refresh
 document.getElementById("dropdown").selectedIndex = 0;
```

function updateData() {alert("hello")}

```
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Your code is poorly formatted. Please ensure that your code is without errors and properly formatted for others to respond. This shows lack of understanding of the subject in general.

Comment: you need to select the code and press ctrl-k for formatting the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The updatedata function is defined after the declaration of the **select widget**. This will not work
Try the below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="dojo/dojo-release-1.9.3-src/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojoConfig = {
            async: true,
            parseOnLoad: true
        };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dojo/dojo-release-1.9.3-src/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/Select"],function(parser){
            parser.parse();

        });
        function updateData(){
            alert("Onchange function called");
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
<select name="select1" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select" onchange="updateData()">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks this does work for the alert. However, what I am trying achieve is to get the value of the selected item and use that in my function. for Example, if I select opt 'A' from dropdown box and try to obtain the value using eval("("+dropdown.value+")"), it simply doesn't work. So deeper question is how do I pass the selection value of the dropdown box to the function? With standard code it works fine but not in dojo? Any help appreciated.

Comment: @user2259146 Replace `onchange="updateData()"` with `onchange="updateData"` and then you can use `function updateData(newVal) { }`. If you have more questions or problems with this, you should probably create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dropDown = new Select({
               name: "select2",
               id: "projectDropDown",
               onChange: function (value) 
               {
                 //console.log("project Id: ", this.get("value"))
                 reScopeProjectContext(value,satpcontext);
               },
               store: projectStore,
               labelAttr: "name",
               value: projectInContext,
               }).placeAt(win.body()).startup();
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for your answer. Rather than just posting a block of code, can you give a short explanation to what the issue is you solved and how you solved it? This will help people who find this question in the future to better understand the issue and how to deal with it.